# Is "面白いな陸" correct?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

https://youtu.be/z4eWwEVQOTs?t=133

Shouldn't it be "面白い陸"? Or does "面白いな陸" have a different meaning?

Comment: I made a faulty assumption with my answer and deleted it to avoid confusing others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not parsing it correctly, I'm afraid. It should be parsed:

> ... おもしろいな。陸の世界の一部になりたい。

Comment: So, it was a trap.

Comment: @DamnVegetables: `<AdmiralAkbar>` It's a trap! `</AdmiralAkbar>`